# Nested shell script doesn't work with list variable

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I have created the following two minimal shell scripts...

test1

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

letterList=$1

for letter in $letterList
do
    echo $letter
done
```

and a second

test2

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

letterList=$1

test1 $letterList
```

When I execute `test1 'A B C'` I get the desired output, `A`, `B` and then `C`.

But when I execute `test2 'A B C'` I expect `test1 'A B C'` to happen, but the actual output is only `A`.

So it appears as though the nested variable list is not somehow being read
– in other words, what is being executed is `test1 A`.

What's going on and how can I achieve the desired result?

P.S.: I'm using OS X, if that's relevant.

Comment: In `test2` replace last line with `./test1 "$letterlist"`

Comment: @kaylum Many thanks! The addition of `"  "` does the trick. The addition of `.\` threw me an error. I assume that it is not necessary since without it it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `./test2 'a b c'` is run we get:

```
$1=a b c
```

So the last line becomes:

```
test1 a b c
```

And when `test1` runs we get:

```
$1=a
$2=b
$3=c
```

That is, the args give to `test1` are not enclosed in quotes and hence they become three args and not one.

To pass `test1` a single arg just enclose the variable in double quotes. That is, replace the last line in `test2` with:

```
./test1 "$letterlist"
```

Note, I have also added `./` to give the path of the executable as it is not good practice to have `.` in `$PATH`.

Comment: It is possible that the OP has placed `test1` and `test2` in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `$HOME/bin`, or some other directory that is in his `PATH`. In that case, prepending `./` is not only not constructive, but rather, harmful (as the OP reports). Of course I agree that **```.```** should not be in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

You have no list variable in your code. You have a string.

The call to `test1` uses the expansion `$letterList` unquoted.  This will make the shell split its value up into multiple words on spaces, tabs and newline characters (by default), and each word will undergo filename globbing (if they contain filename globbing characters).  The resulting words are passed to `test1` as separate arguments.

In `test1`, you only put the very first of these arguments into `letterList`.

If you want to pass the string in `$letterList` as it is to `test1` from `test2`, you need to double quote its expansion in the call:

```
test1 "$letterList"
```

Incidentally, you *rely* on the shell performing the splitting of the `$letterList` value in your loop in `test1` (the same mechanics that cause your issue), but you never protect the code from accidentally performing filename globbing (test your script with e.g. `test2 "A B C *"` to see what I mean).

---

If you want to pass a *list* rather than a single string, then call `test2` with a list rather than with a string:

```
test2 A B C "Hello World" "* *"
```

Then, in `test2`, pass the arguments to `test1`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

test1 "$@"
```

Here, `"$@"` will expand to the list of positional parameters (the arguments to the script), with each individual parameter being quoted.  This means that an argument like `Hello World` will not be split into multiple arguments in the call to `test1`, and the string `* *` will also not get split up into two and no filename globbing will occur.

In `test1`, iterate over the arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for arg in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done
```

or

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for arg do
    printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done
```

... or, if you just want to print the arguments, just

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

I've used `/bin/sh` as the shell throughout as there is nothing here that is specific to `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what your actual objective is. 
The only thing you have said clearly is that you want `test2 'A B C'`
to output `A`, `B` and `C` on three separate lines.

Here is a different solution that will give you that result. 
In general, it seems to give the same output as [kaylum’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561695/80216#561698).

- Keep `test2` the same.
- Change `test1` as follows:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  for letter in $*
  do
      printf '%s\n' "$letter"
  done
  ```

  This, naturally, changes the behavior of `test1`. 
  It now looks at all its arguments, not just `$1`. 
  So `test1 'A B C' 'D E F'` will output `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`
  on six separate lines (instead of just `A`, `B` and `C`).

We normally discourage the use of `$*` because
it breaks strings that contain spaces into separate words. 
For example, `"lazy dog"` would become two words (arguments). 
But that seems to be exactly the behavior you want here.

`printf` is slightly safer than `echo` in the case that a filename
begins with **`-`** or contains `\`. 
That’s been discussed at length on this site;
if you want more information, just search for it.